# Which ports are used on Android when listening to socket.io on a server

Tags: android, socket.io

So let's say I make an Android app and I start the socket.io connection by letting it listen to my API on api.example.com. The API is set up to listen to port 3004.
Does this mean that the Android device itself will open up port 3004 in order to use socket.io?

The reason I am asking is because of a customer that has high security standards, and they want to know which ports are required to be opened in order to use our application.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. I mean Android client will open a port up but unlike server it is not constant. You see unlike server's port, client's port is determined when you connect to a socket server and it may be different every time you connect to one. So it is impossible to say which port however you can use tools like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor and find the port of a specific connection.

Comment: So let's say a company locks most ports, will Android then automatically open up a port that isn't locked or used instead or is it possible that the opened port is one of the ports that are locked by the company and will it then automatically select a different port to be used or not?

Comment: How are you gonna achieve that? Even if you root the android still you can't tell the OS how to manage ports, you may simply create a firewall to block requests.

Comment: Well thing is that we have a customer that has high security measurements en thus only opened the ports that they actually need so I am just wondering how android might respond to such a closed environment and if it would automatically detect on which port it is able to connect with socket.io.

Comment: Impossible with socket.io, However you might be lucky implementing your own TCP socket protocol.